# show ajax html response in a whole webpage

Tags: ajax, response, html

I have an ajax response  -> success : function(response) .

---

This response is in HTML, and I want to display this response in a web page ( not a part of the page div..) but the whole page.

please help me with this issue.

Comment: If you want to load a whole new page … why use Ajax in the first place?

Comment: @Quentin it's used for all pages but only in divs. now I want to do the same but in whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using JQuery, you can do :

```
success: function(response) {
    $("body").html(response);        
}
```

To replace the body of your HTML by your response.